# How can I only see the uses storage with shutil.disk_usage("C:")

Tags: python, python-3.x, module

Entering the command `shutil.disk_usage("C:")`, I obtain the following `usage(total=499462959104, used=407623544832, free=91839414272)`

How is it possible to retrieve *only* the used bytes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Index the second element from the list:

```
x = list(shutil.disk_usage("C:"))
print(x[1]) # 407623544832
```